# Android Studio "Default Activity not found" forced restart after each build

Tags: android-studio

After each build, when I try to build and run the app again on the device, I get:
[image: Default Activity not found]

I have to execute "Invalidate Chaches and Restart" everytime, but after a successful build and flashing the device with the recent generated apk it pops up again...

How can I get rid of that error message permanently?

Comment: Have you checked your manifest to ensure the launch activity is the one you specified?

Comment: @ThomasMorris Yes that is properly. I wouldnt be able to build after a invalidate and restart otherwise